# Include duplicates in for and if loop of array as count number is too small

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm new to javascript so any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I'm trying to do is cycle through every element in the array and count the number of times the value of an element matches a given condition (even if the value is duplicated).

```
function loaddata(xml) {

    var count = 0;
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var z = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("group");

    if (value1 <= value2) {
        for (i = 0; i < (0 + z.length); i++) {
            if (z[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == "John") {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    $('#count1').html(count);
};
```

The count value outputted is too small. I believe the reason for this that the for loop isn't iterating through all elements in the array. When I remove the second if loop and output the count for just the for loop this value is also too small. I believe that the for loop isn't searching through the duplicate elements of the array (i.e. it is ignoring them so that they aren't then fed into the second if loop). Is it possible to specify that the for loop include duplicates?

Comment: Can you show what the data looks like?

Comment: The loop won't ignore anything unless you tell it to. Why do you add 0 to the length of z? That is not needed. `for(var i = 0; i < z.length; i++)` is all you need. Add a `console.log(xmlDoc)` and `console.log(z)` to your code before the if block to see what those values actually are (hit f12 to see the console). I would also, inside the for loop add a `console.log(z[i])` so you can watch what each node is that you are iterating through (btw if you use breakpoints in the js debugger you don't need the console.logs)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick replies. I've added the console.log(z[i]) suggestion and there's no duplicates in xml data it's showing. I think I found the problem, I had imported the xml into excel to do some formulas on it to check that the javscript number would be correct. It seems that the javascript was importing the xml correctly however excel seems to have dupliacted some fields. It seems javscript is outputing the correct number whereas excel isn't. Thanks again for your advice and help.

Comment: You're only checking the first `<name>` tag in each `<group>`. If there are multiple names in each group, you need a nested loop to process all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `console.log(z[i].getElementsByTagName("name"))` and open your browser's console, and see if that array has data in it.

Then `console.log(z[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes)` and make sure you have nodes in it.

Also, do you have many `<group></group>` tags? Because that's what you are selecting with `var z = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("group");`

I hope that helps,